# Java Process with Imagemagick

Tags: java, imagemagick

I want to resize a image, for example: convert 1.jpg -resize 250x240> 1.jpg
I write some code like this:

```
File f=new File(request.getRealPath("/")+"pics/"+d.getTime()+"_"+ttt+suffix);    
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
sb.append("'convert "+f.getAbsolutePath()+" -resize 250x240\\> "+f.getAbsolutePath()+"'");
String command=sb.toString();
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
int returnv=p.waitFor();
System.out.println("command:"+command+" returnV:"+returnv);
```

but I found that, when I add the '>' flag to it, the command fails. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>` character is no flag to the convert command but a redirection of the output into the file `1.jpg`. You could just call `convert` with an output file parameter and avoid the redirection. Instead of:

```
convert 1.jpg -resize 250x240> 1.jpg
```

use

```
convert -resize 250x240 1.jpg 1_resized.jpg
```

BTW, you are escaping you backslashes `-resize 250x240\\>`, maybe this is not necessary and you could simply write `-resize 250x240 >`.

Update: Maybe you could use [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/), a Java library for ImageMagick, instead of executing a system process to convert your image.

Comment: Only Shrink Larger Images ('>' flag)
Another commonly used option is to restrict IM so that it will only shrink images to fit into the size given.   Never enlarge.   This is the '>' resize option. Think of it only applying the resize to images 'greater than' the size given (its a little counter intuitive).

Comment: And you are right, I dont need add \\> to it, just 250x240> is ok, samples in http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink:convert dragon.gif    -resize 64x64\>  exact_dragon.gif, \> is escape for it,right?

Comment: Sorry missed that (used this flag myself at some point but didn't remember). Are the double backslashes necessary, or would one suffice? I guess the backslash is only relevant for the executing shell so it does understand the `>` as character, not redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net) which is a object oriented java wrapper around the ImageMagic command line tools. It solves exactly those problems that you are facing.

[JMagic](http://www.jmagick.org) is another alternativ. It provides a thin JNI layer around the ImageMagic C-API.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime doesn't fire up a fully-fledged shell.   You can of course invoke bash to get one.

Or you can create a thread to sit on the process output stream and write it to an output file.